# Changing the upload folder to another file hosting service?

Tags: php, html, server, directory, server-side

I'm Wondering if it's possible to change the ( media - images - videos - etc. )Folder from local server directory to something like google drive storage and keeping my server storage clean - I don't know what this prosses name in English so please help me out

- you can just give me what to search about and I'll o from there
- or if you have a solution or how this can be done feel free to write it down , that will be more appreciate

thanks

I know linking files from the file directory on the same server not on other server - thanks

this how i link file on php - html

```
include 'file_1.php';
header('Location: http://example.com/file_1.php');
//very basic stuff 

   <script src="myscripts.js"></script> html  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

---

How Can I Link It To Another Server ?

---

Edit + More Clear Idea :

I Want to store files and videos on a different storage service like google drive Microsoft ( OneDrive )

- In a normal server storage system if you upload any file it will create a folder and save the data on it like ( imgs , videos , audios )

[ I Dont want to store it on my server plan that has limited amount of storage i have a google plan that offers 200 GB of storage i want if a client uploaded something in my website i need it to store it on google drive - and if someone need to see the img i need it the fetch it from google drive and view it o my website - i can do this manually but i need it to be automated ]

I Hope this explain it bit more

- sorry for the broken English

Comment: You want to store your pictures on Google drive? Or your PHP code? It's not clear, actually

Comment: i want to store it on google drive - like i need if anyone uploaded a file it will store it in google drive

Comment: i tagged php - because 50% of my backend it's php + MySQL

Comment: You can do that using google's Drive API. But bear in mind that services like Drive are intended for file storage and sharing between individuals and organisations, not for public web hosting. For example, Google puts certain restrictions on Drive which makes it unreliable and difficult to use it as a backend for your website's images. It depends if you simply want to store the data, or whether you want to, for example, embed the images and videos into your website - the latter will be difficult using Drive. There are other solutions, but it depends a bit on your exact requirements.

Comment: oh i see , can you tell me about the other solutions or what to search about (: , to read articles about it ,  & thank u soo much for replying

Comment: Like I said, exactly what you should do depends on your precise requirements. Are you looking simply to store the data and make it available for occasional download? Or do you want to embed these images and videos into pages in your website? These are very different use cases. Also, how much data do you anticipate you'll need to store? And how many people might access it? How frequently do you think the data store will need to be written to, and how often will it be read from? These are all technical / architectural considerations you need to have in your mind when designing this sort of thing

Comment: You should also think about your budget (capital and operational) because most large-scale data storage services will charge you money - both for sending/receiving data, and for storing it. You should consider, speed, location and latency as well, both relative to your main site and to your users.

Comment: (By the way, I'm not asking you to answer those questions right now. And there are probably more you should consider too, those are just what I can think of off the top of my head. You need to go away and think about it, and then do some research into possible solutions based on the factors you've thought about. I can't really recommend anything specific because I won't ever really have all of the available information about your overall solution and its constraints, and also recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: - Are you looking simply to store the data and make it available for occasional download
[ yeah i'm looking for something like Pinterest not all media on it on their server - and it's public ]

Comment: -do you want to embed these images and videos into pages in your website

Comment: [ i'm looking for something more than embed i dont want it just iframe embed i need it to be img src='the-img-link' and there a upload system on my website that clients and login and register and and share post on i want to make things a bit basic on them / they have to upload img and display it after uploading is finshed - like instgram - or youtube ]

Comment: -Also, how much data do you anticipate you'll need to store 
[ im expecting around 200GB - 1TB of file storage ]


-And how many people might access it?
[ 1k - 3k ] expected views 

-and how often will it be read from
[ [ 1k - 3k ] expected views  ]

-How frequently do you think the data store will need to be written to
[ i think 5GB per month or less ]


thanks again for replying (:

Comment: "i need it to be img src='"...that's what I meant by embedding

Comment: Okay Got It , Thank You So Much (:

Comment: i thought you meant <iframe> sorry about that

Comment: Ok. Well I suggest starting to search using terms like "storage backend for media website" and see if any of the products / services / suggestions from those searches would meet all your needs.

Comment: Thank you , i really appreciate you help <3 , you're the best